# Should I let malwaredomainlist.com connect to the net?

Tags: firewall, firefox, malware

I am getting Little Snitch alerts for Firefox trying to connect to the malwaredomains.com with the IP-address 76.63.222.170. I have blocked the connection, but I wonder why Firefox needs to connect to that address? Can I trust it and let it connect?

Comment: That's two different URLs, which is it? Also, which application is making the request?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer to my own question. You can see both the question and answer [here](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1169475). The problem seems to have to do with a firefox plugin named uBlock Origin. In the preferences pane you will find a list of addresses which you can enable or disable. the addresses are related to websites which update maleware sites, etc. It Looks like the malewaredomainlist.com was one of those addresses. In short, it is safe to let it connect to the Net.

Comment: Though your question may be answered somewhere else, your contribution itself doesn't qualify as an answer here because it's only a link. Please edit your answer and add at least a summary and maintain the link as source reference.